# заполнить NaN's среднеарифметическими значениями столбцов в Pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пишу вспомогательную функцию ,которая будет атоматически заполнять `NaN` в `df`.
помогите автоматизировать процесс обращения к колонке датафрейма

```
#заполняет NaN средним арифметическим
def fill(df,column):
    df=df.column.fillna(q(column))
    return df
```

`q()`-функция, считает среднее арифметическое column-условное обозначение колонки

```
(код не рабочий)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
     a    b    c     d
0  1.0  aaa  3.0  10.0
1  2.0  bbb  4.0   NaN
2  NaN  ccc  5.0   1.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN   2.0

In [17]: new = df.fillna(df.mean())

In [18]: new
Out[18]:
     a    b    c          d
0  1.0  aaa  3.0  10.000000
1  2.0  bbb  4.0   4.333333
2  1.5  ccc  5.0   1.000000
3  1.5  NaN  4.0   2.000000
```

`df.mean()` - считает среднее арифметическое для числовых столбцов:

```
In [20]: df.mean()
Out[20]:
a    1.500000
c    4.000000
d    4.333333
dtype: float64
```

`df.fillna(DataFrame2)` - заполнит `NaN` из `DataFrame2`, воспользовавшись индексом `DataFrame2` для определения соответствия значение и имен столбцов в `df`